# Name of different patterns of acting on data in libraries.

Tags: design-patterns, c++, patterns-and-practices

I contribute to a couple of open source software, and I've noticed two types of patterns when classes act on data. I am interested in the name of these patterns.

The first is something that goes like this:

```
class A{
public:
    void compute_something(int* var){
        *var = 2;
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;
    int result;
    a.compute_something(&result);
}
```

Basically, the variable is initialized outside the class and then passed into the class method to be "filled in" with a value.

The second pattern is the usual:

```
class A{
public:
    int compute_something(){
        return 2;
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;
    int result = a.compute_something();
}
```

Here, the method's return type is used to return the value and filling in the variable is made outside the class.

Now is there any name for these types of patterns? And is there a prefered pattern than the other?

Comment: You might want to adjust your examples.  The first is currently just stupid. "Output parameters" (a term I associate with this) are mainly used when there are multiple (sometimes even independent) outputs of different kind. Think a result and a status code.

Comment: Only use out parameters if you already are making use of the return value for something else.

Comment: FYI, in your first example, the variable is not being *initialized* outside the class, but rather merely *declared*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the short version is that the two patterns in the question termed "pass by reference" and "pass by value." Different languages have different levels of support, and different idioms and preferences, for these and other patterns of data management. Stack vs heap-based memory allocation is a related implementation detail.

The deeper answer is that there is a fundamental challenge for programmers around the ownership of memory and lifecycle of memory management. Pass by value is easy but limiting and expensive. Pass by reference is magical but it can become extremely messy very quickly. Innumerable expensive bugs, including most of the most severe security bugs, ultimately arise out of failures to properly manage ownership.

Of popular languages, Rust has gone furthest in describing a set of semantics and giving explicit tools to the programmer to team up with the compiler to make sure that the ownership and lifecycle of particular variables are managed correctly. You don't just pass a pointer, you allow other code to borrow a variable, ownership of which gets tracked by the compiler. The Rust book's treatment of the issue is very good:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html

Comment: hmm is the salient part of the example really the return statement or type? I read it as the calling methodology